# Word for 'a long cylindrical strip'

Tags: word-request

I am in search of a term that denotes an elongated, cylindrical (with circular cross-section) strip. One that you'd use to describe the body shape of a hose (but not hollow) or a phone charger cord, and around that thickness but not rigid (rod).

I need it for a short story I am writing. Here's an example sentence I want to use it in

> The weirdly coloured toothpaste came out in a ...

Here is an image of the kind of object I want to describe.
[image: Short piece of plastic wire]

Comment: Is the object hollow? We might describe it as _tube-shaped_ or _hose-like_. If it really is similar to a worm, _vermiform_ is a fine word.

Comment: If you're just describing squeezed toothpaste why not just say cylindrical? Is the non-rigidity important for this adjective?

Comment: @P. E. Dant No, not hollow, and thanks for 'vermiform' but that would be too specific. I want a more general/wise-encompassing term.

Comment: @C.J. Jackson Yes, I would like an adjective or noun that stresses both length and non-rigidity.

Comment: _"The toothpaste came out of the tube like a weirdly coloured worm."_ (That's called a _simile_.)

Comment: **_NOODLE_**   .  .  .

Comment: @P.E.Dant - _hose-like_ is exactly the word I initially thought of. I really don’t think there is a good single word for this, but I would have upvoted _vermiform_ faster than you can squeeze toothpaste out of the tube.

Comment: Why doesn't *cylindrical* work here?

Comment: @Davo - Because a cylinder doesn't curve, twist, and wind like a snake?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per your comment:

> @Catija, I need it for a short story I am writing. Here's an example sentence I want to use it in: "The weirdly coloured toothpaste came out in a ..."

You honestly don't need a word, as it's common knowledge how toothpaste looks and works when it's squeezed out of a tube.  You can just say it squeezed out like toothpaste.

A good, generic word to describe a significant-but-not-too-long length of toothpaste-like substance that's about hose-like in thickness is *coil*, but this implies it curves a little - your stereotypical marketing picture of toothpaste is like this though.  *Rope* would work if it's very long.  You can use colorful terms like *snake*, *noodle*, etc. depending on the mood of your story.

Comment: Give this man a seegar! @JUNCINATOR should notice this answer. _Noodle_ is spot on: _"...like a weirdly coloured noodle..."_ is exactly the image he's trying to evoke.

Comment: "A rope of toothpaste" works, imho, and is a nice image.

Comment: With some slight rephrasing, I'd agree with "snake"... "came out" isn't a great verb, anyway, particularly in a story... "The oddly colored toothpaste snaked out of the tube when I squeezed it".

Answer (score 1):

The words you could use are *strand*, *string*, and *rope*.  None of them precisely fit your need.  On the other hand, everyone knows what toothpaste looks like when you squeeze it out of the tube, so maybe just drop the sentence completely.

Answer (score 0):

An object which is long, thin, and non-rigid could be a string. An adjective describing an object with these qualities would be [stringy](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/stringy?s=t). If you are describing food, I would instead use [stringlike](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stringlike) because stringy could also mean fibrous when describing food.

Comment: Thanks. But I am looking for something thicker than both a 'string' and  'stringy' would describe.

Comment: @JUNCINATOR the picture you posted is not exactly thick. It seems like the thickness of a shoelace? If that's the case stringy would work.